# In Rotational Dynamics do we have to consider the torque of pseudo force in Instantaneous Axis of Rotation frame?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, torque

In the attached image have I done everything right? If yes then why there is no torque of Pseudo Force?

[image: Why there is no torque of Pseudo Force]

Comment: why there is no torque of Pseudo Force? I don’t see any Pseudo Force F is applied Force

Comment: @Eli That's what I am asking. The object is rotating with alpha and accelerating with 'a'  and if we see the question through IAOR frame there must be a pseudo force and so the above equation must change?

Comment: your equation are correct, can you explain more why you think there is a pseudo force?.

Comment: @Eli Thanks for replying. I think there is a pseudo force because the object is moving and IAOR is a non-inertial frame.

Comment: No your point IAOR is just the instant center of rotation the relative velocity at this point is zero, and nothing to do with non inertial frame

Comment: @Eli Ok I understand Thanks a lot, That's the answer I was looking for. I have a test for Rotational Dynamics, and I was struggling with IAOR a lot. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be a pseudo force acting on the COM of that body. How ever this will not provide any torque because, the instantaneous acceleration of the Point of contact will be $\frac{v^2}{R}$ acting upwards. So when the pseudo force is applied on the centre of mass, it will be pointed downwards passing through the IAOR. Hence no torque will be generated.